# Java Jsoup webscraping

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get the results of this code this way:

> title: Ben 10 Ultimate Alien
>
> comment:taseen_shafquattaseen_shafquat : is there go na a season 4 for
>   this series
>
> title: Akira
>
> comment: dragon3476dragon3476 : one of my most fav animations
>   excellent bit o work and about my 300th watch , i still got the
>   orginal poster from when it came out + dvd and vid and even the
>   t-shirt so yeah i couldn't say anything bad about such a great
>   animation 5/5

But, I get it this way instead:

> title: Ben 10 Ultimate Alien
>
> title: taseen_shafquattaseen_shafquat : is there go na a season 4 for
>   this series
>
> title: Akira
>
> title: dragon3476dragon3476 : one of my most fav animations excellent
>   bit o work and about my 300th watch , i still got the orginal poster
>   from when it came out + dvd and vid and even the t-shirt so yeah i
>   couldn't say anything bad about such a great animation 5/5

**Code**

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

public class WebScraper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url = "http://www.1channel.ch/latest_comments.php";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        for (Element E : doc.select("div.latest_comments > a, div.latest_comments > p")) {

         System.out.print("title: "+ E.getElementsByTag("a").text());
         System.out.println(  E.getElementsByTag("p").text());
          //    System.out.println(T);
            System.out.print("\n");

            try 
            {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/samualdoku/Desktop/Twitter/scraped.txt", true)));
            out.println(E.text());
            out.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
            }  
        }

    }

}
```

And this is the html I am trying to scrape. I think the problem lies with the `href` tag inside the `span`. It contains the commenter usernames.  I called `getElementsByTag("a")` for the title because the title is within an anchor tag. How do I get rid of the span tag, because it prints the title in front of the user names which shouldn't be so.

```
 <div class="latest_comments com_class_tv">
    <a href="/tv-2733767-Dallas/season-1-episode-3">Dallas</a>
    ( 6 minutes ago )
    <p>
        <span class="latest_comments_poster">
          <a href="/profile/jowar">jowar</a>
          :
        </span>
        i just started watchin...eeing as its 34nyrs old
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 String url = "http://www.1channel.ch/latest_comments.php";
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
 for (Element E : doc.select("div.latest_comments)) {

  System.out.print("title: "+ E.select("a").text());
  System.out.println("comment: " + E.select("p").text());

 }
}
```